# Edit text different than question text

Tags: bug, edits

I found [a question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6200533/set-textview-style-bold-or-italic) that I was going to do a little house cleaning on, however when I went to edit it I noticed that the text in the edit box was different than the displayed text of the question. The word "Hi" wasn't shown while editing, but I'm curious if it has something to do with [automatically removing salutations](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/2950/should-hi-thanks-taglines-and-salutations-be-removed-from-posts/93989#93989), which was mentioned right around the same date as the post (Jun 6, '11 vs Jun 1, '11 when the question was posted).

**Rendered text of the question**:
[image]

**Text when editing**:
[image]

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The automatic remove of salutations wasn't retroactively applied, so this ends up being an edge case resulting from that.

I made an edit that changed the body of the question and the new revision also removed "hi".